# jQuery pager not working on last page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My pager works except for the last page that you click on. So if my last page is 11 that has been clicked the pager stops working when going backwards. If you click a page and then click another it works fine except for the last page. here it is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37sfE/4/) (its been updated and working now

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var pageIndex = 1;
function pagerControl(pageIndex, pageCount, step) {
    var result = "";

    if (pageCount > 1) {
        var startPoint = Math.floor((pageIndex / step)) * step;

        if ((pageIndex % step) == 0) {
            startPoint -= step;
        }
        if (pageIndex < pageCount) {
            result += '<a href="#" rel="' + (pageIndex + 1) + '">Next</a>';
        }
        else {
            result += '<span>Next<span>';
        }
        //alert(startPoint);
        for (var i = startPoint + 1; i <= pageCount && i <= (startPoint + step + 1); i++) {
            if (i != pageIndex) {
                result += '<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + i + '</a>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<span>' + i + '</span>';
            }
        }

        if (pageIndex > 1) {
            result += '<a href="#" rel="' + (pageIndex - 1) + '">Prev</a>';
        } else {
            result += '<span>Prev</span>';
        }

    }
    $('#pager').html(result);

    $('#pager > a').click(function (e) {
        reload($(e.target).attr('rel'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
function reload(page) {
    pagerControl(page, 11, 4);
}
pagerControl(1, 11, 4);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37sfE/4/)

Comment: On page 3, when you press "Next", the numbers completely disappear, and the "Prev" link does nothing.

Comment: oh that will have to be fixed aswell do you know how to fix that

Comment: The prev link works upto page 10 then it stops but I don't know why next link jumps

Comment: I've fixed the next link and it works now I've updated my code on jsFiddle but I'm still having problems with the last page being clicked and then clicking backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `' $('#pager a').click '` while binding click event with links instead of present `' $('#pager > a').click '`.

It's working on my side. I know this isn't an elaborated answer but a quick correction.

.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we complicate things too much. How about abolish the "if" statement ... for most cases?

```
    var pageIndex = 1;
    function pagerControl(pageIndex, pageCount, step) {
        var result = '';

        if (pageCount > 1) {
            pageIndex = (pageIndex > pageCount) ? pageCount : pageIndex;
            var startPoint = Math.floor((pageIndex / step)) * step;
            var endPoint = pageCount;

            startPoint = (startPoint < 1) ? 1 : startPoint;
            endPoint   = ((startPoint + step) > pageCount) ? pageCount : (startPoint + step -1);

            result = '<a href="#" rel="' + (startPoint-4) + '">PREV</a>   ';
            for (var i=startPoint;i<(endPoint+1);i++) 
                result += '<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + i + '</a>';
            result += '<a href="#" rel="' + endPoint+4 + '">   NEXT</a>';
        }
        $('#pager').html(result);
        $('#pager > a').click(function (e) {
          reload(parseInt($(e.target).attr('rel')));
          e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    function reload(page) {
        pagerControl(page, 11, 4);
    }

    pagerControl(1, 11, 4);
```

Comment: That doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: Well mc10, it worked fine, as expected, in the jsFiddle. Try it yourself! And, besides, makes it a much cleaner coding.

Comment: I fixed my problem it was the e.preventDefault() after the reload function so I swapped them around and it worked. but thanks for you're answer I might use you're startpoint and endpoint for the {...} part going through the records

Comment: have a look at the jsFiddle now

Comment: Thank you. If you can, at least vote my answer up. Appreciated!

Comment: KDM, your fix does not work: sometimes it shows 3, 4 or 5 page numbers at a time. Nice try though! Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: it was actually this $('#pager > a').click() that was wrong. going to still try you're next and prev buttons though

Comment: Great! Do so! This is fantastic: I have learned a lot lately by helping others here. Have had some ruff time too!

Comment: it works what are you talking about check my jsFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/37sfE/4/

Comment: If you click on next and prev, you will end up with 3, 4 or 5 elements. Just keep on clicking on either the prev or next and you will see.

Comment: I've been clicking back and forth on the numbers and the prev and next buttons but I'm having no problems